# Rewrite equation in c

Tags: c, equation

```
Gain = 255 / (1 - 10 ^ ((Refblack-Refwhite) * 0.002/0.6) ^ (Dispgamma/1.7))
```

Is that a computer language, it looks like c but exclusive or floats doesnt compute. 
Can anybody convert that to c?

thanks

Comment: Just for some context, this is calculating one of the parameters needed in the conversion of cineon log encoded files into linear or monitor space. (Be careful about using the right Dispgamma as its different depending on which of those two cases you are considering)

Comment: X^Y is pow(X,Y) in C. You must #include<math.h> in order to use this function.

Comment: Michael , I'm surprised somebody recognised it.
With the given values of Refblack=95,Refwhite=685 and Dispgamma of 1.0 (paper section 6), we get roughly the square root of a negative number, which bombs in this context.
Is the equation any good at all?

Answer (score 7):

In many languages, `^` is exponentiation. That's the `pow()`, which has the following prototype in `math.h>`:

```
double pow(double x, double y);
```

This computes x raised to the y:th power. So, this makes the equation convert to:

```
#include <math.h>

Gain = 255 / (1 - pow(10, pow(((Refblack-Refwhite) * 0.002/0.6), (Dispgamma/1.7))));
```

Comment: ^ is usually **bitwise xor**. Is that what you meant? Or did you mean to say "math language"?

Answer (score 4):

I guess they mean: `Gain = 255 / (1.0 - powf(10, powf((Refblack-Refwhite) * 0.002/0.6), Disgamma/1.7)))`

Because ^ is normaly xor operator in C. As others used pow it will only use int:s and return a int. man 3 pow for more information.

Comment: Both `pow` and `powf` operate on floating-point data, not integers.  `pow` is for double-precision floats, `powf` for single-precision.

Answer (score 3):

```
gain = 255.0 / (1.0 - pow(10.0,  pow((Refblack - Refwhite) * 0.002 / 0.6, Dispgamma / 1.7) ))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Gain = 255 / (1 - pow(10 , ( pow( (Refblack-Refwhite) * 0.002/0.6) , (Dispgamma/1.7)) ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Matlab code to me

in C, something like that

```
#include <math.h>

float Gain=0;
...
Gain = 255 / (1 - powf(10, powf(((Refblack-Refwhite) * 0.002/0.6), (Dispgamma/1.7));
```